# Selenium Help Needed

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a spreadsheet having two records
Environment   ID
Alpha          1
Bravo          2
Charlie        3

On a web page, I have a drop down for Environment and text box for ID.
I need a code where I am reading the environment and match it with Environment drop down on the web page if it matches I need to pass the corresponding ID to ID text box and click on submit.
Please anyone can share the logic with me in selenium

Comment: You either need to learn coding (there are plenty of free websites, codecademy, EdX.org, etc), or hire a freelancer to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly simple to do, however out of the scope of an SQA question. I advise you look at the following sites for further information on how to complete this.

Using Excel with Python: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

Using Selenium with Python: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Basic Python Logic: https://www.learnpython.org/